# Adminer php docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, adminer

I am trying to upload a .csv file to a database via adminer. It takes up about 100 Mb but I always get this error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16777224 bytes) in /var/www/html/adminer.php on line 1296
```

Adminer and mariadb run on the same docker-compose, and it is as follows:

```
services:

  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb-prueba
    image: mariadb
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
     
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_prueba'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - 2000:3306
  adminer:
    container_name: adminerprueba
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

How can I modify this to be able to upload the file. I have 16 GB of RAM

Comment: Can you check your docker settings through docker UI? You can do checking with this path: "Memory Resource" from Preferences->Resource.

Comment: I don't have those options inside docker desktop. I can only modify within Resources: advanced, proxies, network and wsl integration

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: Docker Desktop 4.7.1